# How can I create a thread in Haskell that will restart if it gets killed due to any reason?

Tags: multithreading, haskell, servant

First some background, I have a requirement where I need to have a config that needs to be updated(by fetching from a Database or an API call) every 10 mins(for example a session token which expires every 10 mins) and it needs to be available to my web server app.

The solution I came up for this is to create a separate long-running thread which will keep on refreshing the config every 10 mins. I will create this thread during application start and need this thread to keep on running as long as the application is running. If this thread gets killed due to some exception, I need to automatically restart it so that it can keep in doing its job.

I tried using `try` to handle any exceptions that might be thrown when my thread is killed, but it doesn't seem to detect or catch the exception.

Code I used:

```
restartableThread :: IO () -> IO ()
restartableThread action = do
  result <- try (forkIO action)
  case result of
    Left (e :: SomeException) -> do
      putStrLn $ "Thread killed due to: " ++ show e
      -- Restart the thread after a delay
      threadDelay 1000000  -- 1 second delay
      restartableThread action
    Right _ -> return ()
```

Is there any other way to make sure my thread doesn't get killed, and if it gets killed, it is restarted automatically?

I'm also open to other ideas for tackling this requirement.

Comment: Seems like a job for `cron`. Just have a separate process that runs every 10 minutes, computes a new config, and communicates that to your main process via a network socket. The operating system is much better at reliably scheduling tasks than you are.

Comment: The 10 mins part is not that important, it can be 11 mins or 9 mins, it just has to keep on updating. The reason I did not consider cron is this config can be of different types, it can be a config from DB or it can be a result of an external API call, or a redis cache value etc. If I go with cron, I'll have to set up separate connections for these in the cron from what I understand. I would like to avoid that if I can and do everything within my application server.

Comment: How do you know this does not catch the exception? What behavior do you observe? At the moment there are not really enough details here to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Your current code "begs the question": you have one thread that restarts its child if necessary, but who restarts *that* thread if necessary? It's possible to mask asynchronous exceptions, but doing so for extended periods of time is ill-advised. Anyway, why do you need to do this? Threads don't just randomly die, and most programs rely on this fact.

Answer (score 0):

Use `try action` to catch exceptions thrown by `action`.

`try (forkIO action)` does not handle exceptions from the action, only exceptions from *forking* the action, which practically never happen.

This function forks a thread that repeats an action every 10 minutes, or retries with a short delay when the action fails.

```
startBgJob :: IO () -> IO ()
startBgJob = void (forkIO (forever (threadDelay tenminutes >> retry action)))
  where
    retry action = do
      e <- try action
      case e of
        Left (_ :: SomeException) -> threadDelay onesecond >> retry action
        Right () -> pure ()
    tenminutes = 600 * onesecond
    onesecond = 1000000
```